# Proper and Correct format of timestamp and time in SQL with Examples

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, types, timestamp

And so I have this error while inserting a data in the SQL using timestamp and time datatypes using DB2 Express-C. Is there any proper format or an example of using this kind of data type? Here is the message regarding this error.

> Overflow occured during numeric data type conversion. SQLSTATE=22003

```
db2 "insert into Accounts(IDNumber, Password, LastComputerUnitUsed, fName, lName, mName, Course, CourseYear, Address, JobPosition, LastLoginTime, TotalTimeAllocated, RemainingTime) values ('11317840', '83QME', '1', 'John Dave', 'Balingit', 'Villarubia', 'BSIT', '2', 'Ozamiz City Philippines', 'Student', '2015-03-15 08:00:01', '100:00:00', '86:34:46')"
```

Comment: Add your sql statement

Comment: The sql statement was all in here in this screenshot. :)

[screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9tmo9rq19dg6xp2/Screenshot03182015.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: Add it to your question as text not as image in a link.

Comment: Are you talking about timestamp? Timestamp data type has nothing to do with date or time in MS SQL Server. If you need date + time data type then you need to use DATETIME or DATETIME2 data types.

Comment: so how it should be done?

Comment: For timestamp, you should use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as your default value, since its gets the current time once you inserted the value. You can also add `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` if you wish to update the timestamp whenever a new value is updated on a certain column.